# Kendo UI filter menu close event?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Hello implemented a custom filter menu using checkboxes similar to this example:

http://dojo.telerik.com/@SiliconSoul/oBoCu

My problem is if the user selects/deselects some checkboxes but then never clicks the "Filter" button. I would basically like to reset their selections to what they initially had before the menu closes but don't think the filter menu has such an event.

How can I bind to the menu closing?

Comment: you could capture the clear filter button to load the default filter you like

Comment: I am not trying to clear the filter. I need a way to bind to the filter menu closing so I can reset the checkbox selections if for some reason the user opens the filter menu, changes their checkbox selection but then never clicks on filter or clear buttons and just closes the menu.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like the filter menu is a kendoPopup, which has a close event.

```
$(#my-popup).data("kendoPopup").bind("close", function (e) {
  console.log("filter menu closed");
});
```

Since I used the filterMenuInit event of the kendoGrid, you can access the filter menu container via Event.Container

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#events-filterMenuInit

```
event.container.data("kendoPopup").bind("close", function (e) {
  console.log("filter menu closed");
});
```